# Monitor Nextcloud connections with netstat

Tags: tcpdump, netstat, nextcloud

I'm not able to detect incoming connections from Nextcloud sync clients via netstat on my server.

I have a server in my LAN, running Nextcloud with MySQL in docker containers. I use multiple Nextcloud Clients (Linux, macOS and iOS), everything is working fine.

I want to check if clients are connected to my server on host level. With netstat I'm able to see if a client is connected via the Nextcloud web UI, but I don't recognize connections of the Nextcloud sync client.

Does anyone know the netstat parameter I'm missing? Any hint is welcome.

BR Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connections are probably DNATed to the containers. That means the host is now acting as a router between "outside" and the containers. `netstat` will not display those connections. You will need additional tools for the missing flows.

One such tool is [`conntrack`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/conntrack/conntrack.8.en.html), which queries conntrack about tracked connections. Using this command with option `-j`:

```
conntrack -L -j
```

will display only NATed connections, thus showing the current active established flows between the containers and outside and complementing the output of `netstat`.

If you want an output similar to `netstat` you could try if available [`netstat-nat`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/netstat-nat/netstat-nat.1.en.html) which more or less relies on the same mechanism.

An other method, to run in a loop, would be to query Docker (using `docker` directly on the host) about each container's main pid and use the result to access the container's network, to run an usual `netstat`. This has the advantage of displaying certain states not showing anymore with conntrack (like `CLOSE_WAIT`, usually a symptom of problems on an application).

Given a running Docker container named `containername`, this should get all its network connections, as seen from its own point of view, even if the container itself lacks any useful command for this:

```
nsenter --target $(docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' containername) --net netstat -utn
```